# Load Balancing SOAP requests

Tags: multithreading, performance, soap, iis-7, load-balancing

I have a SOAP web service that is running on Windows 2008 R2, IIS7, ASP, and .net v2 framework. The service connects to a 32-bit dll that performs an operation that typically takes 15ms to complete. I have a requirement to manage 100 simultaneous requests per second originating from a single IP address.

Having followed many threads in this forum and the Microsoft site I have been able to tune my service to achive up to 50 simultaneous requests, using soap-ui and load-ui as a test harness.

I think that my only option is now to load balance several servers. Having read about load balancing and tried a virtual application from loadbalancers.org I'm not sure how to load balance the SOAP requests from a single IP, they only seem to balance based by IP address. Is this possible?

Regards, Mark.

Comment: You should probably consider optimizing the performance of that application first. To answer your question: you're looking for a round-robin load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Server with Network Load Balancing this is absolutely possible.

Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691.aspx for more information on it.
It should be standard with your server install.

There are other options but this will be your fastest and easiest since it seems you already have the necessary components.